# NullPointer exception ONLY when deleting multiple music files

Tags: android, android-file

I'm adding the ability to delete songs in my music player app.

I have the below two methods that are used for deleting songs.

```
public static boolean deleteSong(Context c, String songId) {
    long id = Long.parseLong(songId);
    Uri songUri = ContentUris.withSppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    String filePath = getPathFromUri(c, songUri); // my custom method for getting file path
    // Delete file
    boolean deleted = (new File(filePath)).delete();
    // Delete from MediaStore database
    if(deleted)
        c.getContentResolver().delete(songUri, null, null);
    return deleted;
}

public static int deleteSongs(Context c, ArrayList<SongItem> songs) {
    int failednum = 0;
    boolean deleted;
    for(SongItem song : songs) {
        deleted = deleteSong(c, song.getId());
    if(!deleted)
        failednum++;
    return failednum; // return number of files that were not deleted
}
```

The `deleteSong()` method works absolutely without any problem. The `deleteSongs()` method also works but **very often** (almost always) when the`songs` ArrayList is large (3 or more items), I get the NullPointer Exception. What is `java.io.File.fixSlashes` anyway?

The logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25300): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
E/AndroidRuntime(25300): Process: com.example.player, PID: 25300
E/AndroidRuntime(25300): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at com.example.player.Utils.deleteSong(Utils.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at com.example.player.Utils.deleteSongs(Utils.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at com.example.player.AllSongsFragment$DeleteSongsTask.doInBackground(AllSongsFragment.java:362)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at com.example.player.AllSongsFragment$DeleteSongsTask.doInBackground(AllSongsFragment.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(25300):        ... 4 more
```

And here's the `getPathFromUri()` method

```
public static String getPathFromUri(Context c, Uri contentURI) {
    String result = "";
    Cursor cursor = c.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there a concurrency issue with getPathFromUri() where it may be returning a null file path?  Have you tried logging that value?  Do you see the same issue without the thread pool executor?

Comment: I ran the deleteSongs() method only once yesterday without an AsyncTask and I didn't get any error. I'm using AsyncTask now because it takes some time to delete many items.

Comment: @GaryBak I've added code of getPathFromUri(). Do you see anything that might be of issue here? Maybe opening and closing the cursor is the problem here?

Comment: First thing to try would be to change your AsyncTask to .execute() instead of executeOnExecutor(), this would allow you to see if your issue is related to multiple deletes running in parallel.

Comment: The issue indicated by the logcat is totally misleading. I had another problem with ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception outside deleteSong() or deleteSongs() methods with another ArrayList object. Fixing that also fixed the problem here. I don't know how it happened as the the problems are not related at all, but the problem are gone now. Thanks for your time guys. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is you're trying to create a file with a `null` file path. Try checking to see if `filePath` is null before this line:

```
boolean deleted = (new File(filePath)).delete();
```

Try this:

```
boolean deleted = false;
String filePath = getPathFromUri(c, songUri); // my custom method for getting file path

// Delete file (if filePath isn't null)
if(filePath != null)
    deleted = (new File(filePath)).delete();
else
    Log.v("DEBUG", "filePath of song with id #" + songId + " is null");
...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll try this now. Even if `filePath` were null, I cannot underatand why it would be so, since deleteSong() by itself never gives the error. Only deleteSongs() causes the error.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam Well in truth all `deleteSongs()` is doing is calling `deleteSong()` multiple times so it looks like something inside `deleteSong()` is the culprit but only when it's called multiple times.

Comment: hmm...I'll take a further look at getPathFromUri() method. I'll also post it here. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I think it might be that cursor.close() happens in the background and before it is completed, another instance of cursor is opened. Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: @DavidHeisnam It looks like you're either getting an empty cursor object or null from `c.getContentResolver().query()`, try checking for either of these cases and logging the issue to find out what's happening.